# Microchart not visible in sapui5 tile container

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to show microchart in my tile container. But  I don't know what is wrong with it. I have a single tile. which have some small charts like a progress bar, pie charts etc. none of my tile showing these. I've included the namespace for charts which is "xmlns:micro="sap.suite.ui.microchart"

```
<CustomTile  >
        <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
            <l:content>

                <FlexBox height="70px" width="170px">
                        <micro:HarveyBallMicroChart isResponsive="true" total="100" totalScale="Mrd" showTotal="true" showFractions="true" app:name="harvey ball" press="press">
                            <micro:items>
                                <micro:HarveyBallMicroChartItem fraction="63.5" color="Good" fractionScale="Mrd" />
                            </micro:items>
                        </micro:HarveyBallMicroChart>
                    </FlexBox>
            </l:content>
        </l:VerticalLayout>
    </CustomTile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put away:

```
<FlexBox height="70px" width="170px">
</FlexBox>
```